# How to assign value from a named range in one worksheet to a cell in the active worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to archive data from formatted worksheet called BOD_Labsheet to one called Data. I have done something similar using UserForms but am encountering problems here.

When I run the macro, I get the error "Method 'Range' of object _Worksheet failed" on line

```
dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, 2) = bodWorksheet.Range("BOD_Lab_Date").Value
```

The Data worksheet is active when I do the copying.

Should I simply copy all the values from BOD_Labsheet to an array, activate the Data Worksheet and recopy values?

Here is the complete code:

```
    Sub Submit_BOD()
'
' Submit_BOD Macro
'
Dim dataWorksheet As Worksheet, bodWorksheet As Worksheet, suspendedSolidsWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim dataSheetName As String
Dim bodSheetName As String
Dim suspendedSolidsName As String

dataSheetName = "Data"
bodSheetName = "BOD_Labsheet"
suspendedSolidsName = "Suspended_Solids_Labsheet"

Set dataWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(dataSheetName)
Set bodWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(bodSheetName)
Set suspendedSolidsWorksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(suspendedSolidsName)

Dim myRanges() As Variant
myRanges = Array("BOD_Collected_By", "BOD_Temp_Out", "BOD_Temp_IN", "BOD_Source", "BOD_Sample_Vol_4", _
                "BOD_Dilution_1", "BOD_Blank_IDO_4", "BOD_Blank_FDO_4", "BOD_Sample_Vol_7", "BOD_Dilution_2", _
                "BOD_Blank_IDO_7", "BOD_Blank_FDO_7", "BOD_Seed_IDO_13", "BOD_Seed_FDO_13", "BOD_Seed_IDO_14", _
                "BOD_Seed_FDO_14", "BOD_Influent_IDO_15", "BOD_Influent_FDO_15", "BOD_Influent_IDO_16", _
                "BOD_Influent_FDO_16", "BOD_Effluent_IDO_20", "BOD_Effluent_FDO_20", "BOD_Effluent_IDO_21", "BOD_Effluent_FDO_21", _
                "In_BOD_Concentration", "Out_BOD_Concentration")

'Make Data Sheet active
dataWorksheet.Activate

Dim myDate As Date
myDate = DateValue(bodWorksheet.Range("BOD_Lab_Date").Value)


Dim yearAsString As String, monthAsString As String, dayAsString As String
yearAsString = Format(myDate, "yyyy")
monthAsString = Format(myDate, "mm")
dayAsString = Format(myDate, "dd")

Dim reportNumberText As String
reportNumberText = "NP" & yearAsString & monthAsString & dayAsString
Debug.Print "reportNumberText = "; reportNumberText

'Determine emptyRow
Dim emptyRow As Integer
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
'Sample Number
dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = reportNumberText

'Date and Time Collected

dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, 2) = bodWorksheet.Range("BOD_Lab_Date").Value
dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, 3) = Format(bodWorksheet.Range("BOD_Collection_Date").Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, 4) = Format(bodWorksheet.Range("BOD_Read_On_Date").Value, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For i = LBound(myRanges) To UBound(myRanges)
j = i + 4
dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, j) = bodWorksheet.Range(myRanges(i)).Value
Debug.Print "dataWorksheet.Cells(" & emptyRow & "," & j & ") " & dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, j).Value

Next i

ActiveWorkbook.Save

suspendedSolidsWorksheet.Activate
Range("SS_Date").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: How did you set the names of all of your ranges in the myRanges array?

Comment: I would expect that error if you didn't have the named range "BOD_Lab_Date" in `bodWorksheet` worksheet.  I would check that before trying to copy things to arrays and then re-copy.  That seems to add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "BOD_LAB_DATE" more than one cell? Maybe your method usually works also, but I usually would copy a range of cells by reversing your order and using copy, like so:

```
bodWorksheet.Range("BOD_Lab_Date").Copy dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, 2)
```

Comment: That did the trick. Your answer also reminded me that BOD_Lab_Date referenced a merged area. That seems to be why my original code would not work, because did work for the lines that followed which only referenced single (non-merged) cells. Thanks!

Comment: As a follow-up, the problem did stem from trying to copy the value from merged cells. The faster and cleaner solution is to use single cells and then use something akin to  dataWorksheet.Cells(emptyRow, j) = bodWorksheet.Range(myRanges(i)).Value